# How to pass file name to two commands in single line

Tags: git, git-bash, git-config

I want to combine two commands in a single line as follows.

I want to execute these two commands.
1. dos2unix dir/file_name
2. git add dir/file_name

I want:

**dos_add = dos2unix | git add file_name** 
so dos_add is my  alias.

in git-bash it should like:
**c:\dir(dfsds4343) $ dos_add dir/file.txt**

Which executes dos2unix and git add both on a file.

Comment: `dos_add() { dos2unix "$1"; git add "$1"; }` . It's a function, not an alias.  Aliases have been essentially deprecated for decades.

Comment: hi, @WilliamPursell Thanks for the reply.
Please,  would you show me how to do this? I am not sure where to add a function or create. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @WilliamPursell

It can be done by
*1. hit this command into gitbash*

```
gitbash:$ code ~/.gitconfig
```

add following code

```
[alias]
    ad = "!ad() { dos2unix.exe "$1" && git add "$1"; }; ad"
```

just use:
**gitbash:$ git ad filename.text**

Comment: That is definitely an appropriate use!  My comment referring to the obsolescence of aliases was referring to shell aliases, and should be retracted for this usage.  I had been thinking to add the function to ~/.bashrc, but this is appropriate.